# How do remove cart item in redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am new to ReactJS and Redux. In my application I have CartPage that displays all CartItems along with Remove Button to remove any of the Cart item.

Below is snippets of my code for reducer to remove the cart item but this code seems not working.

Below I want remove customerCartItem inside array How can I remove helps me

Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this

```
//action
export const deleteCustomerCartSuccess = payload => ({
  payload,
  type: constants.CUSTOMER_CART_DELETE_SUCCESS,
})


   import * as constants from '../constants/CartPage';    
        const initialState = {
          customerCartDetails: {},
          id: ''
        };
        const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
          switch (action.type) {
            case constants.CUSTOMER_CART_DETAILS_SUCCESS: {
              return {
                ...state,
                customerCartDetails: action.payload.data,
              };
            }
            case constants.CUSTOMER_CART_DELETE_SUCCESS: {
              console.log('REMOVE_REDUCER', action.payload, state.customerCartDetails.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id));
              return {
                ...state,
                customerCartDetails: state.customerCartDetails.CustomerCartItem.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)
              };
            }    
            default: {
              return state;
            }
          }
        };


//Component 

 removeCartItem(index) {
    const { deleteCustomerCartSuccess } = this.props;
    deleteCustomerCartSuccess(index)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

```
    // Create a types.js to hold all your action constants
    import { CUSTOMER_CART_DETAILS_SUCCESS, CUSTOMER_CART_DELETE_SUCCESS } from './types'

    // Not necessary, but if you'll be logging a lot, consider destructuring
    const { log } = console;

    const initialState = {
      // This should be an array, not an object, if you'll be using the filter method
      customerCartItem: [],
      // When initializing, make sure to set to initial state to empty arrays, objects and null values
      id: null
    };

    const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      // Destructure these two from the action object
      const { type, payload } = action;
      switch (type) {
        case CUSTOMER_CART_DETAILS_SUCCESS: {
          log('CUSTOMER_CART_DETAILS_SUCCESS', payload.data);
          return {
            ...state,
            customerCartItem: payload.data,
          };
        }
        case CUSTOMER_CART_DELETE_SUCCESS: {
          log('REMOVE_REDUCER', payload);
          return {
            ...state,
            // After your edit:
            customerCartItem: state.customerCartItem.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id)
          };
        }    
        default: {
          return state;
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: I am Getting error like state.customerCartItem.filter is not a function. insidecustomerCartItem multile arrays is there please once read question again.

Comment: Because `customerCartDetails` is an object, not an array. The [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is for arrays

Comment: then which way I have to delete the cart item.

Comment: Change `customerCartDetails` to be an array. Every time you add an item to the cart, push an object to `customerCartDetails`, that looks something like, `{ name: 'Item-1', price: 100 }`

Comment: I have changed array format still I am getting error customerCartItem.filter not a function.

Comment: Instead of doing `state.filter(...)` in the reducer, try sending the modified payload. So, that way, you will have `dispatch({ type: CUSTOMER_CART_DELETE_SUCCESS, payload: someFilteredArray })`. It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong with your code without seeing it all. What does `log('REMOVE_REDUCER', payload);` print?

Comment: Hi Mike still I am stuck in delete cart item task request you too help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207481/discussion-between-bharath-mb-and-mike-k).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove all items from the cart

in reducer

```
const initialState = {
  items: {},
  totalAmount: 0,
};
```

in switch case

```
 case CLEAR_CART:
    return  state={ items: {}, totalAmount: 0, }
```

this is from action

```
export const clearCart = () => {
  return {
      type: CLEAR_CART
  }
}
```